I want to connect two Smart Tables to a single Smart Filter in SAP Fiori
I have created two Entity Sets in SAP and I want the data from each method to be displayed in each Smart Table.
view.xml)
<sfb:SmartFilterBar reset="onReset" search="onSearch" 
id="smartFilterBar" entitySet="PEBAPSTSet,PEBATRSet" persistencyKey="UniqueAndStablePersistencyKey"  
                            beforeVariantFetch="onBeforeVariantFetch" afterVariantLoad="onAfterVariantLoad">

<st:SmartTable id="smartTable"
                                            entitySet="PEBAPSTSet"
                                            ...
                                            requestAtLeastFields="SecurityId,DealNumber,BookPosAmt,PositionCurr,Portfolio"
                                            dataReceived="onTableReceived"
                                            beforeRebindTable="onBeforeRebindTable">

<st:SmartTable id="smartTable2"
                                            entitySet="PEBATRSet"
                                            ...
                                            requestAtLeastFields="SecurityId,SecurityAccount,SettleKamt,PositionCurr,EventType"
                                            dataReceived="onTableReceived"
                                            beforeRebindTable="onBeforeRebindTable2">

<sfb:ControlConfiguration label="asset" id="assetCode" key="AssetCode" index="2" visibleInAdvancedArea="true">

<sfb:customControl>
<MultiComboBox id="AssetCode" selectionChange="onComboBoxChange" 
items="{ path: '/ListBoxSet', templateShareable:false}">
<core:Item key="{Text}" text="{AssetCode}"/>    
</MultiComboBox>
</sfb:customControl>

</sfb:ControlConfiguration>

The two Entity Sets were created with a Complex Type and an additional field(AssetCode).
I want to enter conditions in the Smart Filter and have those condition values appear in the SAP Method when I click the execute button, but the data isn't being entered. I've looked everywhere for a solution, but I can't find one. Does anyone know how to fix this?
controller.js)
onInit: function() {
            this.oSmartFilterBar = this.byId("smartFilterBar");
            this.oSmartTable = this.getView().byId("smartTable");
            this.oSmartTable2 = this.getView().byId("smartTable2");

onBeforeRebindTable: function(oEvent) {
            this.oSmartFilterBar = this.byId("smartFilterBar");
            var oDateValue = this.byId("Grdat").getValue();
            var oBindingParams = oEvent.getParameter("bindingParams");
            console.log('oBindingParams',oBindingParams);
            
            if (oDateValue) {
                var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Grdat", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, oDateValue);
                oBindingParams.filters.push(oFilter);
            }
            
            this.onComboBoxChange("AssetCode", oEvent);
            console.log('oDateValue',oDateValue);
        },

..............................
